# I haven't been here for a year, but it says I have

Tags: bug, design, yearling-badge

Just yesterday I saw this pop up in my achievements cup:

[image: Screenshot of Achievements Notification]

I haven't even been on Stack Overflow for that long, let alone here. So what happened?

I did earn 200 reputation, but I haven't been here for a year.

<sub>Windows, with Chrome browser. Didn't eat breakfast today. Please don't redact this badge from me :D</sub>

Comment: Are you sure? Your profile here on MSE says you've been a member for a year and 6 months.

Comment: I dont think it matters how long you were actually active, i think it matters how long your account existed *at all*, and it probably doesn't matter how long you took to get 200 rep too.

Comment: You've been on a few sites for 18 months, how is it that the [FAQ](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/188731/282094) is unclear?

Comment: Maybe an account merge took place?

Comment: Worth noting that on MSE time flies ...

Comment: Everyone, I haven't been here that long! I think @rene is correct. I created my StackOverflw account first, and I haven't earned yearling there. So what happened?

Comment: @Rob I have been here for 2 months. Not 18 months. Don't you think I'd know? I haven't earn't yearling on StackOverflow, so how would I here?

Comment: @mindstormsboi again, I haven't been here for 18 months, only 2 months.

Comment: @AdamLear I haven't been here for 18 months, only 2 months. How else would I only visit the site for 109 days?

Comment: 109 days is more than 2 months anyway.

Comment: @rene time flies like an arrow. Fruit flies like a banana.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The account you're now using on this site (Meta Stack Exchange) was created in 24th to March, 2019. That's year and half ago, which is over a year:

[image: profile page with join date and reputation]

Once you got over 200 rep, you received the Yearling badge.

Numbers do not lie.

You might have created the account in that time, forgot about it, created a new one, and the new one got merged into it.

Congrats for your new badge.

Comment: Ohhh! I understand! I had a really old account called Programmer. I deleted it after a while, but not this one. An account merge may have happened. Thanks for the exact date.

Comment: Yeah, so you deleted the SO profile, and forgot you had one here as well. All good. :)